# How can I increase the output parameter of a boost converter based on tthe MC34063?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, boost, step-up, mc34063

I would like to get 16.5V and 160mA output using an MC34063 IC. The circuit is designed on Multisim shown as a picture below.  It provides the desired output.

[image: Multisim circuit]

In practice, this circuit has set as shown in picture does not próduce the desired result. The voltage is lower than designed. What is the reason for this situation?

Comment: What is the desired voltage and what does it produce on a light load and on full load? How good is your inductor and how good is your supply at remaining at 5 volts when the circuit is loaded? Isn't R1 too big to deal with the shown output load?

Comment: Try smaller... what is that, R2? It's hard to read with the labels overlapped like that. Preferably use an actually good regulator or controller like CS5171, LM3481 (or a zillion others I don't have numbers handy for, alas), which can save greatly in component size, cost and efficiency.